# main(java.lang.String) already declared in main(String args[]) error displayed

Tags: java, program-entry-point, java.lang.class

When I compile the following code it shows this error: `main(java.lang.String) already declared in main(String args[])`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] array1 = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            array1[i] = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();
    int[] array2 = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
        if (sc.hasNextInt())
            array2[i] = sc.nextInt();
    median(array1, array2);
    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: Please post the complete source code for the file.

Comment: Why you close Scanner above.

Comment: your braces `{}` are all wrong. Use them to wrap `for` and `if` statements.

Comment: I think you'll want to include some more braces.

Comment: Can you show where it is already declared?  Your code is not complete enough to work out what the problem is.

Comment: When you close the scanner, it closes System.in and you can't read from it any more.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting "already declared" because you have the following line of code twice...

`for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)`

`for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)`

if you want to use you code as-is, you'll need braces...

`for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    //some code
}`

`for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    //some code
}`